# Can't initialize static array with what I think is supposed to be a compile-time constant

Tags: c, arrays, static, initialization, constants

I'm trying to initialize a static array with the size based on what I think should be a compile-time constant.

This is easily fixable but simply not using static, but I didn't expect this issue to show up at all. This might cause me other issues in the future.

The relevant sections:

```
typedef struct {
    GPIO_TypeDef* Port;
    uint16_t Pin;
} PortPin;

typedef struct {
    I2C_HandleTypeDef *Handle;
    uint16_t Address;
    PortPin Interrupt;
    PortPin Shutdown;
} VL53L1_Dev_t;

//This one is bigger but I've kept it short to keep it readable. It's 3 elements in my code
static VL53L1_Dev_t Sensors[] = {
    {//1
            &hi2c2,
            0x52,
            {
                    GPIOA,
                    GPIO_PIN_11
            },
            {
                    GPIOA,
                    GPIO_PIN_10
            }
    }
}
static const int sensorCount = sizeof(Sensors)/sizeof(Sensors[0]);
static uint8_t encodedData[sensorCount * 2];//Compiler doesn't like this part
```

Since Sensors is fully defined on compile-time, I expected sensorCount to also be a compile-time constant. Which apparently it isn't because I can't use it to declare and initialize static arrays. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size of an array declared at file scope must be an **integer constant expression**.  It is defined in section 6.6p6 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> An *integer constant  expression* shall  have  integer  type  and 
>   shall  only  have  operands that   are   integer   constants, enumeration   constants,   character   constants, `sizeof` expressions 
>   whose  results  are  integer  constants,
>   `_Alignof` expressions,  and  floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts.  Cast operators in an integer constant expression 
>   shall  only  convert  arithmetic  types  to  integer  types,  except 
>   as  part  of  an operand to the `sizeof` or
>   `_Alignof` operator .

So the contents of a variable, even if declared `const`, are not part of such an expression.

If however you define `sensorCount` as a macro, the expression `sizeof(Sensors)/sizeof(Sensors[0])` *is* a compile time constant.

```
#define SENSOR_COUNT  (sizeof(Sensors)/sizeof(Sensors[0]))
static uint8_t encodedData[SENSOR_COUNT * 2];
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason this can't be changed in the standard? From a logical standpoint the compiler should be able to differentiate between variables that could be compile-time constants.

Comment: @Tryphon That's the way it's been.  A `const` *is* considered a constant expression in C++, but not in C.